# having issues using Emmet-mode

Tags: spacemacs, emmet

Am new to Emacs and am using Spacemacs, Emacs mode. After following the basic Emacs tutorial, I create an html file and try to use emacs for code editing. So I installed the html layer, after activating emmet-mode, it still stuck at web-mode. And I got any autocompletion. Like typing :`.my-class` + TAB don't generate any code.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable/configure `auto-completion` mode perhaps?

[Spacemacs Autocompletion](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/auto-completion)

Comment: I just check this but auto-completion is already enabled :/

Comment: `web-mode` should aromatically enable `emmet`, if I am not mistaken. At least I did not add anything special, aside from my emmet configuration. Try this: restart emacs. `M-m` or `space` depending on edit mode, then `f` -> `J`, then enter HTML as extension. Then try from scratch.

Comment: Also, what engine are you using for autocomplete, company (suggested) or auto-complete? And did you enable it globally? `(global-company-mode)` in the `dotspacemacs/user-config`?

Comment: I found out that i needed to hit `Ctrl-j` to make it works. :)